# Android Native Kotlin Jetpack Compose update to observable not rendering

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I’m relatively new to writing code with Jetpack Compose for an Android Native application. I thought I understood how state works, but the more I work with it, the more I realize I don’t really have a clue.

I have a setting that I am saving in a `preferencesDataStore`. However, the problem I am seeing now isn’t related to the datastore. I have a setting that I have put into my view model, that shows up on a splash screen (you can check the setting so that you won’t see the splash screen anymore). When I change it on the splash screen, I can see in my code that it is being changed, but the checkbox in the UI never reflects my change. I’m sure I’m doing something really stupid, and hoping someone can find it.

Here is the option in my view model:

```
@HiltViewModel
open class SettingsViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    val bypassSplashScreen = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
```

Here’s the related code in my splash screen:

```
@Composable
fun splashScreen(mainViewModel: MainViewModel) {
    val settingsViewModel = mainViewModel.settingsViewModel
    var bypassSplashScreen = settingsViewModel.bypassSplashScreen.observeAsState().value
…
Checkbox(
    checked = bypassSplashScreen!!,
    onCheckedChange = {
        LogHelper.logDebug("$MODULE_NAME.$FUNCTION_NAME: in onCheckedChange before - bypassSplashScreen = $bypassSplashScreen")
        bypassSplashScreen = !bypassSplashScreen!!
        LogHelper.logDebug("$MODULE_NAME.$FUNCTION_NAME: in onCheckedChange after - bypassSplashScreen = $bypassSplashScreen")
    },
)

Text(
    "Do not show this screen at startup",
    fontSize = 18.sp
)
```

When I click on the checkbox in the UI, the value in the field is being changed (see log below), but the UI never shows the box being checked.

My log looks like this:

```
D/ClaimFactionSelector: SplashScreen.splashScreen(): in onCheckedChange before - bypassSplashScreen = false
D/ClaimFactionSelector: SplashScreen.splashScreen(): in onCheckedChange after - bypassSplashScreen = true
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `.value` on state, it just becomes another variable and by updating it you are just updating the value of the field instead of state!

```
@Composable
fun splashScreen(mainViewModel: MainViewModel) {
    val settingsViewModel = mainViewModel.settingsViewModel
    var bypassSplashScreen = settingsViewModel.bypassSplashScreen.observeAsState()
…
Checkbox(
    checked = bypassSplashScreen.value,
    onCheckedChange = {
        LogHelper.logDebug("$MODULE_NAME.$FUNCTION_NAME: in onCheckedChange before - bypassSplashScreen = $bypassSplashScreen.value")
        bypassSplashScreen.value = !(bypassSplashScreen.value)
        LogHelper.logDebug("$MODULE_NAME.$FUNCTION_NAME: in onCheckedChange after - bypassSplashScreen = $bypassSplashScreen.value")
    },
)

Text(
    "Do not show this screen at startup",
    fontSize = 18.sp
)
```

**Edit**

The reason you are not able to set value is because `bypassSplashScreen` is not a `MutableState`, `observeAsState`  returns `State`, the better approach here would be to update the `LiveData` on checked change which in turn updates the state!

```
@HiltViewModel
open class SettingsViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    val bypassSplashScreen = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    
    fun setBypassSplashScreen(value: Boolean) {
       bypassSplashScreen.value = value
    }

//then in Splash screen
@Composable
fun splashScreen(mainViewModel: MainViewModel) {
    val settingsViewModel = mainViewModel.settingsViewModel
    var bypassSplashScreen = settingsViewModel.bypassSplashScreen.observeAsState()
    …

    Checkbox(
        checked = bypassSplashScreen.value,
        onCheckedChange = {
        LogHelper.logDebug("$MODULE_NAME.$FUNCTION_NAME: in 
        onCheckedChange before - bypassSplashScreen = $bypassSplashScreen.value")
        bypassSplashScreen.value = !(bypassSplashScreen.value)
        LogHelper.logDebug("$MODULE_NAME.$FUNCTION_NAME: in onCheckedChange after - bypassSplashScreen = $bypassSplashScreen.value")
        },
   )

    Text(
       "Do not show this screen at startup",
       fontSize = 18.sp
    )
```

**Tip:** Also, if your app is entirely in Kotlin, it is better to use `flows` or `stateflow` directly in `viewmodel` rather than using `LiveData`

Comment: Thanks @Rajan Kali. Unfortunately, trying to set the `.value` does not work for some reason. It is telling me that "Val cannot be reassigned", even though `bypassSplashScreen` is a var in this module, and in my `settingsViewModel` it is also a var:   `var bypassSplashScreen = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()`

Comment: @DaveWesterman Updated the answer in edit based on your comment!

Answer (score 1):

In Compose UI recomposing don't take as Value maintain as the State.

Maintain your state variable as Immutable (val) with initial values for default state of the UI.

```
    @Composable
fun splashScreen(mainViewModel: MainViewModel) {
    val settingsViewModel = mainViewModel.settingsViewModel
    val bypassSplashScreen by settingsViewModel.bypassSplashScreen.observeAsState(initial = false)
…
Checkbox(
    checked = bypassSplashScreen!!,
    onCheckedChange = {
        LogHelper.logDebug("$MODULE_NAME.$FUNCTION_NAME: in onCheckedChange before - bypassSplashScreen = $bypassSplashScreen")
        bypassSplashScreen = !bypassSplashScreen!!
        LogHelper.logDebug("$MODULE_NAME.$FUNCTION_NAME: in onCheckedChange after - bypassSplashScreen = $bypassSplashScreen")
    },
)

Text(
    "Do not show this screen at startup",
    fontSize = 18.sp
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Thirumaran. But if I change the field to this: `val bypassSplashScreen by settingsViewModel.bypassSplashScreen.observeAsState(initial = false)`, then the line below where I try to change the value fails because you can't update a `val`.

Comment: @DaveWesterman, In UI level we do not change any values, To change the values use viewmodel only, we can call the viewmodel fun from the view part.